# gapi.auth.authorize callback doesn't get called when doing sign-in via Google on node-webkit app

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, node-webkit, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I have an issue when doing sign-in from node-webkit app. In the node-webkit application, I open a page on my domain with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
             var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';               

            function authorization() {
                   gapi.auth.authorize({
                     client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                     immediate: false,
                     scope: SCOPE
                   }, function(authResult) {
                        alert('CALLBACK');
                      }
                   );
                 }
        </script>       
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=authorization"></script>
        <title>Google Sign In</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

For some reason the callback never fires when running on node-webkit. While trying to debug it I saw something strange. When I run this from node-webkit, this code will open the google sign-in screen. When the node-webkit developer console is open for the google page, the callback fires successfully.

When I load the same page on chrome, the callback fires and I can see the alert, so I don't think the issue is with the code. Before running this code I programmatically clean the node-webkit cache so each time the user is required to enter his credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this using a different approach. Since this question was left unanswered for over 2 months now, I will describe which workaround I've used.

Instead of doing the sign-in using Google js library, I used server side authentication. I chose the [Google PHP SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php). This is the flow I used:

1. From node-webkit, I opened a page (php) from my server on a new window.

   ```
   exports.login_window = window.open(url,{
       "position": "center",
       "focus": true
   });
   ```
2. using Google SDK, I generated an authentication link and redirected the client to that link.

   ```
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setClientId($client_id);
   $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
   $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
   $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
   $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
   header('Location: '.$authUrl);
   ```
3. once authenticated, the client redirected back to my server.
4. using google API I queried for all the information I needed. Than I stored the information on the document session

   ```
   "sessionStorage.google_data = ".json_encode($data).";"
   ```
5. from the original page (when I opened the login window), I polled the new window session, and once the google_data was there, I pulled it and closed the window.

   ```
   if (
       typeof exports.login_window == "undefined" ||
       exports.login_window.window == null ||
       typeof exports.login_window.window.sessionStorage == "undefined" ||
       typeof exports.login_window.window.sessionStorage.google_data == "undefined" ) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           check_3p_login();
       },200);
   } else {
       var google_data = exports.login_window.window.sessionStorage.google_data;
      // rest of the code
   }
   ```